# Laravel - Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot error al intentar transformar web en imagen

Tags: laravel, packages, puppeteer

estaba probando el paquete de `spatie/browsershot` basicamente el paquete te da la funcionalidad de poder convertir en una imagen los sitios webs que le pases por url (entre otras cosas). Yo estaba haciendo una prueba muy simple, en un **ubuntu server**. Es el siguiente:

(Como estoy con el nano y tal lo estoy haciendo desde el propio fichero de rutas de laravlel para no crear todo el mvcdesde un nano y ahorrarme mas problemas, total, estoy testeando)

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::url('https://www.youtube.com/')
    ->save(storage_path('test.pdf'));
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Basicamente me tendria que devolver una imagen (o mejor dicho, PDF) de la url que recibe, en este caso de **youtube**.

Pero al cargar la pagina welcome (donde estoy llamando esta funcionalidad directamente) me indica el siguiente error:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/html/test/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/","action":"pdf","options":{"path":"\/var\/www\/html\/test\/storage\/test.pdf","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}}}'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/html/test/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Error: Failed to launch the browser process! /var/www/html/test/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-884014/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md at onClose (/var/www/html/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:194:20) at Interface.helper_js_1.helper.addEventListener (/var/www/html/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:184:68) at Interface.emit (events.js:203:15) at Interface.close (readline.js:397:8) at Socket.onend (readline.js:173:10) at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Imagen del mismo error que lo mostrado arriba  de arriba: https://gyazo.com/df45493adeaf66b1a7cedfc455127c5e

---

Por otra parte, el package es este : https://github.com/spatie/browsershot . Que indica que hay que tener npm instalado con el package **puppeteer** . Yo entiendo que el error tiene que ver a lo mejor con no encontrar los binarios, pero tambien le pase le path de los binarios de node y npm pero ni aun asi funciono.

Dentro del proyecto laravel, si ejecuto esto :  `npm list  --depth=0` me dice que está el paquete:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/html/test#  npm list  --depth=0
/var/www/html/test
└── puppeteer@10.0.0
```

Asi que no se que puede estar pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, por lo visto necesitaba archivos.so para en el sistema, que me los ha indicando el propio lravel con cada error, a medida que arreglaba uno me pedia otra dependencia (dependencias del sistema,no del propio laravel). Aqui las instalaciones que hice :

```
   48  sudo apt install nodejs
   50  apt install npm
  138  npm install puppeteer
  320  sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-tools
  337  sudo apt-get install libnss3
  339  sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0
  340  sudo apt-get install -y libxkbcommon-x11-0
  342  sudo apt-get install libgbm.so.1
  343  sudo apt-get install libgbm.so
  344  sudo apt-get install libgbm
  345  sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0
  346  sudo apt-get install -y libcairo2
```

PD: los comandos parecidos es porque me equivocaria en la sintaxis, pero los dejo, ques mejor que sobre a que falte. =D

---

En la llamada en el codigo, le he tenido que pasar unos parametros:

```
 ->addChromiumArguments([
      'no-sandbox',
  ])
```